# "The efforts involved" vs. "the effort involved"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

> …this we are doing proactively in order to have a better understanding at coming up with an estimate in case you want to know the effort involved.

Should I go with "efforts" or "effort" in the statement above? I cannot make up my mind; both options look okay to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for great explanation, everyone. Picking one up as an answer for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use *effort*. You need a mass noun there, like *work* — and indeed, *effort* in that sentence means *the total work involved*.

*Efforts* indicates attempts, which you don't really want to imply, even if they were ultimately successful.

[ODO on effort](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/effort)

> **effort**: the result of an attempt:
>   *he was a keen gardener, winning many prizes for his efforts*

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [this forum post](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1928219), "efforts" is used when

1. Multiple people work separately on the project, or
2. One person has been repeatedly unsuccessful but keeps trying.

In your example, neither of the above applies, so I would use "effort".

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use "efforts," simply because you are referring to a group of people.  I am assuming that every member of your group is putting in an individual effort - collectively, they are efforts.

You could use "effort" in the singular, however, if you want to present your organization in a more unified light, talking about the singular effort of the entire group - it takes away the individuality of each member, but it still conveys roughly the same message.

That, however, is a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

The choice between *effort* and *efforts* is the least of the problems you need to sort out in this sentence. Singular *effort* is just fine, as it happens, but the rest of the sentence imposes a quite unreasonable burden of interpretation on the reader.

In so far as I understand it all - and it is difficult to do so without the context - I think it might mean something like:

> We are taking the initiative in doing this because you may want to
>   have some idea of the effort involved. We hope that what we have done
>   will give us a better understanding of how we might come up with an
>   estimate for you.

Am I on the right lines?